# Best approach to automate generation of Azure Data Factory assets

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have a scenario where we want to use Azure Data Factory to copy data from multiple Azure SQL DBs to Azure Data Lake Store. Since there are a lot of different DBs owned by different groups, we want to automate the copy process including the generation of pipeline, copy activity based on a configuration. What is the best way to achieve this ? Currently we are looking at Azure .Net SDK but again there will be a lot of code to manage.

Comment: I have used PowerShell in the past to auto-generate Data Factory objects; the nice thing here is you can use the PoSh script to read the metadata from the Azure SQLDB, use the resultset to generate the ADF JSON files and deploy those files to Azure. To simplify this I created templates of the datasets and activities with the known values and plugged in the variables from the resultset

Comment: thanks for the reply, will try that approach. Sounds cleaner and more straight forward that using .NET SDK

Answer (score 1):

If you're just doing a dynamic copy, the new V2 Azure Data Factory has a [Lookup Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) that can probably do what you need without generating a pipeline on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

What we ended up doing was to build an ADF Mapping table (sql table, json, excel, any tabular structure that you'd like) that basically has the definition of our pipelines and its dependencies end to end, so it flattens out a hierarchy with levels 0-N.

And then we created a python library that reads from that ADF Mapping and creates the datasets, copy activities and pipelines using this python SDK/library:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/azure-mgmt-datafactory

We take into account many parameters like the number of activities per pipeline (so far we use 30) as we have had issues in the past, Microsoft has actually enhanced this ever since so you could go with more and see if it works for you. For more info here are the data factory limits:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/azure-data-factory-limits.md

Sometimes we just have a one to one mapping to land data into our SQL landing layer, those are very straightforward but it definitely helps us to create hundreds of objects that previously were manually created (one-by-one).

This orchestration becomes more complex upstream in your process when there are many dependencies and transformations but I guess that documenting the Mapping is key to overcome this. Also, getting the mapping in place is tedious if you have a mature project so you may want to semi-automate the generation of it as well, depending of how our ELTs look like. In our case we used python to get a hierarchy tree of all of these dependencies listed out and then parse this into a mapping.

Hope this helps.